# ExtJS 4.2.1 - panel.add() function not defined in prod build

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.2, sencha-cmd

im adding components to my Panel dynamically with the add function of the panel like this

```
this.add(Ext.ComponentManager.create(this.buildItems()[0]));
```

where `this` is my component extending an `Ext.panel.Panel`.

While developing this works like a charm.
Though when i use sencha cmd (`sencha-4.0.4.84 app build`) and build the production build.
There is no function `add(...)` in my panel defined and the line fails.

Any ideas? Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if you get any "Synchronous Warning" in console while developing. If yes, fix them.

Comment: yeah thx. i had some axis and series classes not in my requires array included.